# Использование слова "Причина" и запятые с этим словом

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика, выбор-слов

Подскажите, уважаемые, как быть со словом "причина" и как правильно использовать его в предложении? Где расставлять запятые при использовании этого слова?

- Причина тому, то, что...
- Причина тому, то что...
- Причина этому, что...
- Причина этому, то, что...
- Причина этому, то что...
- Причина в том, что...
- Причина того,...
- Причина ... в том, что...
- Причиной того, является то, что...

Какие варианты являются правильными?

Comment: «Где расставлять запятые при использовании этого слова?» ========= Как может имя существительное влиять на пунктуацию?

Comment: 1) Для определения правильности варианта желательно привести полное предложение.  2)Причина тому/этому (Д.п.) -  это неправильно, можно сказать причина этого (Р.п.). 3) Повторы некорректны: "причиной того, является то, что".  4) В ответе я привожу  грамматические варианты, которые используются в реальной речи по данной теме.

Comment: @Sibylla https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Причиной+тому&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=25&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CПричиной%20тому%3B%2Cc0 а как же это, я знаю лично, что это правильно, другой вопрос, как это правильно использовать?

Comment: Да, причина тому/этому встречается в текстах, например:  Причина этому ― объективные обстоятельства или бюджетная политика". "Причина тому проста".  Но эти формы используются в простых предложениях без повтора указательных слов. Интересно также то, что мы говорим "причина пожара", но не "причина пожару".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оборот со словом «причина»  чаще используется в официально – деловом  или научно – популярном стиле.
Причина (причиной) чего? или чему?
1. Чего? (при выражении зависимого слова существительным). Причина конфликта. Причиной задержки явилась несвоевременная доставка.
   2. Чему? (при выражении зависимого слова указательным местоимением). Причиной тому (этому) были непредвиденные обстоятельства. Причина тому — новое оборудование
(http://www.sekretarskoe-delo.ru )
Знаки препинания расставляются с учётом того, что «причина» - обычное существительное ,   то – указательное местоимение в разных падежах, а что – подчинительный союз
Причина тому  то, что...
Причина этому то, что...
Причина в том, что...
Причина ... в том, что...
Причиной этому является то, что...

Comment: Это стопроцентная информация?

Comment: Девяностодевятипроцентная информация (я шучу). Уважаемый SovereignSun, выйдите на сайт, там указана ссылка

Comment: Спасибо. уважаемый.

Answer (score 2):

1) Толковый словарь предлагает **два варианта составного союза** для придаточного причины:

ПРИЧИНА,   **По причине того что; по той (простой) причине, что**, в зн. союза. Из-за того что, потому что.

Они опять вернулись назад **по причине того**, что вы неправильно указали номера счетов или перепутали написание фамилий. [Маша Трауб. «Умный еврей» (2009)]

― Но, ― продолжал иноземец, не смущаясь изумлением Берлиоза и обращаясь к поэту, ― отправить его в Соловки невозможно **по той причине, что** он уже с лишком сто лет пребывает в местах значительно более отдалённых, чем Соловки... [М. А. Булгаков. Мастер и Маргарита, часть 1 (1929-1940)]

2)Эти варианты СПП с придаточным изъяснительным: Основной п**ричиной является то, что** потенциальные антивирусные средства либо довольно токсичны, либо их активность невысока.

**Причина заключается в том, что** в цивилизованном мире курить стало не модным и даже неприличным. Только это соображение стало **причиной того,** что я написал данную статью.

Comment: Это не то, что я искал.

Comment: Вот уже понятней стало.